# Modify oh my zsh default command prompt to have complete path for current directory

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I want to modify oh my zsh default command prompt to have complete path for current directory from home. I want :

```
➜  ~/parentFolder/myFolder git:(master)
```

instead of :

```
➜  myFolder git:(master)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To achieve that, paste the following line at the end of your `.zshrc` file:

```
PROMPT='${ret_status} %{$fg[cyan]%}%~%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info)'
```

Comment: This completely breaks my ZSH prompt (even though it does technically show the full path now). All of the other stuff in my prompt is gone. Here is my old prompt: https://i.imgur.com/16g0sLD.png

Here is my new prompt (after adding the line):
https://i.imgur.com/7u0gJtL.png

Comment: @RaleighL.  I'm not sure what happened in your case, but the accepted answer worked fine for me and the others. It's quite an old question, maybe something has changed and is outdated now.